# Arrays in a Palindrome program

Tags: c

So I made a program where I have to input a word and it displays if it is a palindrome (a word that is the same both ways) or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    char word;
    int length, counter;

    printf("Please enter a word: ");
    scanf("%c", &word);

    int flag = 1;

    for (counter = 0; counter < length && flag; counter++) {
        printf("%c\t %c", word[counter], word[length - counter])
        if (word[counter] == word[length - counter - 1]){
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
    if (flag) {
        printf("%c is a palindrome!", word);
    }
    else {
        printf("%c is NOT a palindrome!", word);
    }
}
```

I set it up so that it displays each letter side by side. If a letter isn't the same then the flag is "thrown"(set to 0) and this will end the program saying: "word is NOT a palindrome!"

I get an error at the part where it says word[counter] saying it isn't a subscripted value. What can I do to make this work? Is there anything else I am doing wrong?

Comment: `char word;` is char not array?!!

Comment: `char word` says `word` is a character. `char word[]` will make word as `array`.

Comment: I would recommend `flag = 0; break;` rather than testing in the `for` condition. It makes it easier for someone reading your code. It has already been pointed out that you are not using character arrays correctly. Also not sure why you are printing `[counter]` and `[length-counter]`, but comparing with `[length-counter-1]`. The former will be out of bounds when `counter==0` (since the last valid element is `[length-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

This `char word;` is not an array. This `char word[100];` is an Array. Also you read a single character using `scanf("%c", &word);` not a word (as in a string or series of characters). Use:

```
fgets (word , 100 , stdin)
```

Also `length` is not initialized, so it will lead to UB.

Comment: It's even better to not have to explicitly repeat the length of the array. You can do this instead: `fgets(word, sizeof word, stdin)`.

Answer (score 0):

Make this modifications in your program.It will run fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
    {
    char word[100];
    int length, counter;

    printf("Please enter a word: ");
    scanf("%s",word);
    length=strlen(word);
    int flag = 1;

    for(counter = 0; counter < length/2 && flag; counter++) 
        {
        if (word[counter] != word[length-counter-1])
        {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag) 
    {
        printf("%s is a palindrome!\n", word);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s is NOT a palindrome\n!", word);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has a buffer overflow when you enter a word longer than 100 characters. Use `scanf("%100s", word)`.

Answer (score -2):

```
****************************************************************
*              Simple Array Palindrome Program                 *                               
****************************************************************/
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
int arr_size;
int flag=0;
/*****************************************
 *             Array Size                *
 *****************************************/

cout<<"Enter The Array Size: \n->arr[";
cin>>arr_size;cout<<" ]";
int arr[arr_size];
/*****************************************
 *             User_Input                *
 *****************************************/


for(int i=0;i<arr_size;i++){
cout<<"Enter Value For Arr[ "<<i<<" ]  -> "; 
cin>>arr[i];
} 
/*****************************************
 *           Palindrome_Check            *
 *****************************************/


for(int k=0,j=arr_size-1;k<arr_size && j>-1;k++)
{

if(arr[i]==arr[j];
{
flag++;
}

}
/*****************************************
 *             Flag Check                *
 *****************************************/


if(flag==arr_size) {
cout<<"Array Is Palindrome: ";
}
else
{
cout<<"Array Is Not Palindrome: ";
}


}
```

Comment: Not sure the C compiler will like `ostream`s and `namespace`s.

Comment: First, providing C++ code as an answer to a question tagged as C is wrong. But aside from that, please avoid giving code-only answers. Instead, try to explain how your code solves OP's problem. Nobody wants to wade through your code to figure out what you have done when you could so easily place your answer in context.